# How to place three jar files?

Tags: java, jar

I am new in Java, I want to run a Java program, it needs three jars: swt-3.6M3-win32-win32-x86.jar，DJNativeSwing-SWT.jar,DJNativeSwing.jar. I have them, but I do not know where I should put them. Can someone help me?

the following is the import codes:

```
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeComponent;
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface;
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.components.JWebBrowser;
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.components.WebBrowserAdapter;
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.components.WebBrowserEvent;
```

Comment: *"I want to run a Java program"*  When it comes time to deploy the Java program, look to use [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS make it simple to add extra Jars to the run-time class-path, and for the user it is as easy as 'click the launch button & follow the prompts'.

Answer (score 2):

Add them to your class path. In Eclipse: Right click the project>Properties>Java Build Path then add them as external jars.